# How to divide each element in a list by every element of that list

Tags: python

I am new to Python. I have been stuck on a rather simple problem.
I have a list
r = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
I want to divide each element of the list by every other element

I want the output to be 2/2, 2/3, 2/4, 2/5, 2/6, 2/7, 2/8, 2/9, 2/10, 3/2, 3/3 and so on

I have tried

```
for i in r:
    print(i/i)
```

But the output I get is

```
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
```

What should I do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should do 2 for loops, for every element, you need to iterate over all the elements of the rest of the list.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use list comprehension to archive this:

```
r = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
[print(x / y) for x in r for y in r]
```

Which is somehow (it is not exactly) the same as:

```
for x in r:
  for y in r:
    print(x / y)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! The code worked. But did I do wrong and did the nested for loop work?

Comment: You need to nest two fors to divide each value against the others. Only with one for you (as in your question) you divide every value against itself. `i/i` would be 2/2, 3/3, etc...

Answer (score -1):

You could use nested for loops like this:

```
r = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for x in r:
    for y in r:
        if (x.index() != y.index()):
            print (x/y)
```

The comparison is used to make sure that each element doesn't print itself divided by itself

Comment: Thanks for this! But why is it not working without nested for loops?